# Only make specific wars skinny in an EAR using maven-ear-plugin

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, ear, maven-ear-plugin

Is there any combination of configuration options I can use with the maven-ear-plugin to create an EAR with skinny wars, but specifying that I want a specific war not to be modified?

I have a requirement in which I would want one WAR to be deployed as-is, maintaining all its libs in its own WEB-INF/lib folder.

I realize that this may be duplicating libs in the /lib folder as well as the WEB-INF/lib folder, but I would like this war to remain static - that is have all its libs remain self-contained.

Is this feasible?  Will it cause a class loading conflict if the same lib exists in WEB-INF/lib as well as /lib?  Is there a way to restrict visibility from the /lib folder?

Comment: What's not clear is why you would like to keep only one war as is and don't reduce the size ...?

Comment: @khmarbaise I was asked to keep a war static to ensure that all its dependencies are self contained and that there would be no chance of conflicts with other libs in the EAR.  I'm not sold on the concept either, but was asked if this was feasible.  I could only come up with a solution where I would package the ear first and then explode it, add the war and rezip the EAR - a fairly ugly soln.